# Могу ли я управлять позицией пользователя при использовании history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Постраничная навигация, которая подгружает след страницы через `ajax`, добавляя в урл параметры и сохраняя его в историю, но проблема в том, что при переходе на любую страницу после подгрузки `>=1` раза пользователь нажимает клавишу "назад", и попадает на страницу `../../?page=some`, но его сразу кидает в футер.
Пробовал через

```
var stateData = {                   
    scrollTop: "500px",
};
window.history.pushState(stateData,'',newurl);
```

Но всеравно кидает вниз.

Comment: А откуда у Вас инфа, что различные свойства первого аргумента функции pushState на что-то влияют? Судя по инфе, например, от [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), Вам нужно помимо этого определить на странице событие window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {...});

Comment: то-есть вы предлагаете каждый раз при клике пользователя по истории (вперед назад), искать свой `state`, и в случае если это моя страница, скролить его вверх?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский это событие срабатывает только на документе, на котором я добавлял их, то-есть при переходе на совсем другую страницу, и опять при клике "назад", я в него не попадаю